# Saving a Pulse Audio stream with Haskell bindings

Tags: haskell, audio, io, pulseaudio

Using the [pulse-simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pulse-simple) package I have made the following code:

```
main=do
    s<-simpleNew Nothing "example" Record Nothing "this is an example application"
      (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1) Nothing Nothing
    xs<-simpleRead s $ 44100*10 :: IO [Float]
    simpleFree s
    play xs

play :: [Float] -> IO ()
play d = do
    s<-simpleNew Nothing "example" Play Nothing "this is an example application"
        (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1) Nothing Nothing
    simpleWrite s d
    simpleDrain s
    simpleFree s
```

This works and records 10 seconds of audio and then plays it back.

I now want to encode and save the audio file (as a .wav rr whatever) so it can be played in another program or converted. I think that this is more of an audio question so for the non Haskell people I basically have an array of floats which is 44100*10 long. I suspect I'll need some other library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the `Data.WAVE` module from the [WAVE package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/WAVE-0.1.3/docs/Data-WAVE.html) should do the job.

Convert your `[Float]` to `[Int32]` and that constitutes the `waveSamples` field of the `WAVE` record. Fill in the rest of the `WAVEHeader` and write the file using `putWAVEFile`.

```
import Data.WAVE

writeWaveFile :: String -> [Float] -> IO ()
writeWaveFile path floats = putWAVEFile path wave
  where wave = WAVE wHeader wSamples
        wHeader = WAVEHeader { waveNumChannels = 1
                             , waveFrameRate = 44100
                             , waveBitsPerSample = 32 -- or maybe 8?
                             , waveFrames = Nothing
                             }
        wSamples = [[ ... | x <- floats ]]
```

Fill in `...` with a suitable `Float -> Int32` function.